# Autocomplete short symbol names in non-global context

Tags: front-end, version-9, keyboard, autocomplete

Is it possible in v9 to autocomplete the short symbol names when one is operating in a context other than `` Global` ``? I.e. after evaluating the following:

```
Begin["MyContext`"];
xyz=5;
```

Starting to write `MyCon`... will autocomplete and give `` MyContext`xyz `` as an option. That's not what I want. I want to write `x` and get autocomplete to suggest `xyz`. I tried adding `` MyContext` `` to `$ContextPath` but that doesn't do anything. Of course if I were to exit `` MyContext` `` and return to `` Global` `` I don't expect it to autocomplete the short name anymore. Also, I noticed that the symbol coloring is off too, so that `xyz` appears to have no value assigned (blue colored) even though it obviously does have a value.

Comment: In M9 all defined variables are autocompleted - is it not what you need?

Comment: Yes, it autocompletes for me too. Re: your second question, you can do ``SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
 AutoStyleOptions -> {"SymbolContextStyles" -> {"MyContext`" -> 
      Green}}]``

Comment: That's strange. It doesn't autocomplete for me, and I tried it both on Mac and PC, and using 9.0.1... I do exactly what I said above, and unless I type MyCon... nothing happens. If I just starting typing x it just sits there.

Comment: Hmm.. I think I can reproduce it if I do `Begin[...]` and work in it without calling `End[]`. The problem is that the FrontEnd has not yet recognized the new context (which it does when you call `End[]`) and my guess is that when you call it with the full context, it is the kernel that is providing this information. If you instead do `Begin[...];AppendTo[$ContextPath,...];End[]; Begin[...]`, it works i.e., create your context and add it to the path, close it so that the FE recognizes it and then switch to it again. Enter those in separate lines, not as one.

Comment: Does it auto-complete if you just do xyz=5; ?

Comment: Ok yes now it works. It requires that I call `End[]` as well as that I add it to `$ContextPath`. Doing either individually doesn't do the trick.

And yes, if I just do `xyz=5;` in the ``Global` `` context it does autocomplete. (After having evaluated it obviously.)

Comment: It autocompletes for me. However, for add-on packages, the little drop down button on the RHS does not work properly for me ... it is meant to load that functions Help page ... and this does not appear to be working for add-on packages, even if the >> link from ??FunctionNameHelp works fine for the same function name. This would appear to be a bug in v9.

Comment: Actually there's a little caveat that I just noticed. If I include the following in a single cell: `Begin[...];AppendTo[$ContextPath,...];End[];Begin[...];` it does _not_ work. Instead I have to break it up into two separate evaluations. Specifically, first I must evaluate `Begin[...];AppendTo[$ContextPath,...];End[];` and then follow it with `Begin[...];`

Comment: @MohammedAlQuraishi That is exactly why I told you to enter it in separate lines (see my prev. comment) :)

Comment: @rm-rf, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

Paraphrasing the insights of rm -rf:

- To make highlighting and autocompletion work in new contexts you have to run: 1) `Begin[...];` 2) `AppendTo[$ContextPath,...]` and 3) `End[]`. Then you have to open your context again: `Begin[...];`
- Be sure to put each of (1), (2) and (3) in the previous bullet point in separate cells. They have to be evaluated separately or it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you please provide a working example, because my auto-completion still does not work, when I repeat what you say.